# How can I include a method pointer in a typed constant?

Tags: delphi

I'd like to use procedure of object in a record, like so:

```
TCommandRec = record
  name: string;
  fn: procedure of object;
end;
```

I can create an array with this by assignment:

```
commands: array [0..1] of TCommandRec;

...

commands[0].name := '-help';
commands[0].fn := DoHelp;
commands[1].name := '-load';
commands[1].fn := DoLoad;
```

What I'd really like to do is declare a constant:

```
const
  cmds: array [0..1] of TCommandRec =
  (
    (name: '-help'; fn: DoHelp),
    (name: '-load'; fn: DoLoad)
  );
```

However, I get errors for DoHelp and DoLoad - Constant expression expected. These are two methods of a class. Is there some syntax I need to use to make this work or am I stuck building the array at runtime?

Comment: No, method pointer does not qualify as constant expression (mainly because of instance pointer - see TMethod.Data).

Comment: @user539484 Method pointers with constant subjects are constant expressions

Comment: @David Heffernan, do you have an example?

Comment: @user Yes, in my answer

Comment: @David Heffernan, good one! Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A method of object is what is known as a two pointer type. It encapsulates the following information:

1. The address of the function.
2. The address of the object, or the subject.

The former is known at compile time but generally the latter is not. Which is why you typically need to create these things at runtime.

If you can arrange that the subject is known at compile time then you can declare a typed constant of your record type. For example:

```
type
  TMyRecord = record
    Foo: procedure of object;
  end;

  TMyStaticClass = class
    class procedure Foo;
  end;

class procedure TMyStaticClass.Foo;
begin
end;

const
  MyRecord: TMyRecord = (Foo: TMyStaticClass.Foo);
```

Of course, that's only going to be useful to you if your functions are viable as class methods rather than instance methods. I'm just adding the code above to illustrate that you can have constant method pointers, so long as the subject is a compile time constant.

Comment: I like this answer - I can use class procedures as the class is just acting as a dispatcher for command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You can store pointers to methods in your records (these are known at compile-time, so no problem specifying them in a const definition):

```
TCommandRec = record
  name: string;
  fn: Pointer;
end;

...
const
  cmds: array [0..1] of TCommandRec =
  (
    (name: '-help'; fn: @DoHelp),
    (name: '-load'; fn: @DoLoad)
  );
```

Then, when you need to call `fn` of `cmds[i]` (I suppose that the call occurs inside the same class which defines the `DoHelp` and `DoLoad` methods), write something like:

```
type TObjectProc = procedure of object;
var m: TMethod;
...
m.Code := cmds[i].fn;
m.Data := Self;
TObjectProc(m);
```

Comment: On modern Delphi you may choose to use new style RTTI for such a runtime approach. Have the constant store the name of the method and Invoke via RTTI on a specific instance.

Comment: Yes, thanks. If I remember correctly, RTTI works only for `published` methods.  But it's less efficient than storing a pointer (although performance probably is not important here), and compiler won't warn us if we have a typo in the method's name or if we rename an appropriate method in the class.

Comment: New style RTTI is not based on published. It's a trade off between performance and not relying on implementation detail.